# change dropdown menu selection using cherrypy

Tags: python, html, drop-down-menu, cherrypy

I am already building a server with cherrypy, and I want to change the current selection of a drop down menu using cherrypy, Is that possible, I looked around but I found it can be done using selenium does cherrypy offer a way to do something similar ?  I can write a dummy python code with replace to change the html letter but I want a smarter solution.